# How to write a case-sensitive query in java named queries

Tags: java, jpa, named-query

> @NamedQuery(name = "TblBanLookUp.findBAN", query = "SELECT t FROM
>   TblBanLookUp t " +        "WHERE t.businessUnit = :businessUnit AND
>   t.customerCode = :customerCode")

This is the current code which returns case insensitive result set. (it returns result that has both "bu1" and "BU1" as the business unit).

In SQL this can be overcome using the BINARY keyword.

> SELECT businessUnit FROM TblBanLookUp WHERE businessUnit = BINARY
>   'bu1' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50;

But I'm not sure how to write the named query related to this, without changing the database.

Comment: have you tried `lower( t.businessUnit ) := :businessUnit`

Comment: it's not always lowercase, it should match with what ever the value in the database.